# jQuery not showing image on click

Tags: jquery

Can anyone advise on whats wrong here? all the images appear after button click apart from div6 which doesnt show at all? Have I got code wrong on dix6 somewhere, any help much appreciated!

Many thanks!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
   <script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn(2000);
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
        $("#div4").fadeIn(5000);
        $("#div5").fadeIn(7000);
        $("#div6").animate({ left: '250px' });

    });
    });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
    <button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
    <br />
    <br />
   <div id="div1"style="display: none">    
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage1.png" alt="about" width="150" height="75" /></a>
    </div>
  <div id="div2" style="display: none">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage2.png" alt="about" width="150" height="75"/></a>
  </div>
  <div id="div3" style="display: none">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage3.png" alt="about" width="150" height="75"/></a>
  </div>
  <div id="div4" style="display: none">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage4.png" alt="about" width="150" height="74"/></a>
  </div>
  <div id="div5" style="display: none">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage5.png" alt="about" width="150" height="75"/></a>
  </div>
   <div id="div6" style="display: none">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/myimage6.png" alt="about" width="150" height="75"/></a>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: You want `div6` to come sliding in from the right?

Comment: I want the div to come in from the left and stop after some padding-left 200px; or so...

Answer (score 3):

Your div is still hidden, `animate` doesn't remove the `display:none`

try

```
$("#div6").animate({ left: '250px' }).show();
```

Comment: @ManuM what do you mean? Show() here doesn't animate and as animate is async, DIV is shown at same time (nano seconds after) animate start

Comment: I mean, by using your code you cant see the animation since the animation takes place first and then only the div appears. So there no use of animate function. Got it?

Comment: @ManuM but he is not using animate callback. BTW, it's not my code ;)  http://jsfiddle.net/h2dTU/  Or http://jsfiddle.net/PaA87/  Can you see any difference?  That's said, your answer is more consistent in this regards

Answer (score 3):

You are not showing the div  but just animating.. Use like this.

```
$("#div6").show().animate({ left: '250px' });
```

Comment: Strange someone downvote it! Could downvoter explain because looks like exactly what OP is looking for!

Comment: I can see the image now but its not animating, can the image slide in from the left? and stop after some padding left? Thanks

Comment: Dont know if the site is blocked but I cant see anything just cop of coffee and header?

Answer (score 1):

try this, this will help you

```
 $("button").click(function () {
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn(2000);
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
        $("#div4").fadeIn(5000);
        $("#div5").fadeIn(7000);
        $("#div6").animate({ marginLeft: "+=50px" },
                  {
                      duration: 500,
                      complete: function () {
                   $("#div6").show();       
                      }
                  });

    });
```

fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/WD546/)

Comment: I don't understand purpose of animating a hidden object?!

Comment: What I need guys is all 6 divs to animate from left and stop on screen about 200px, so padding-left: 200px;

Comment: yes you also apply animation to all 6 div and also padding on it instead on marginleft

Comment: Is it possible to have all the images in the divs here to come in from the left and go to the right and stop? I know I have .fadein but I would like to keep this so fadein then add then .animate as seen on div6, can you advice how to fix this, currently Im not seeing any animation on div6 but the other divs are fading in ok...many thanks!